# How to Retrieve value from DropdownFormField?

Tags: flutter, dart

I used dropdownformfield to get the gender of user in the sign up page, I created the widget in other class, I wanna know how can I control the field or retrieve the value when it changes because it doesnt have a controller unlike textformfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest adding an onChanged callback that can be passed into the constructor of the class containing the dropdown field.

```
class DropdownField extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function(dynamic) onChanged;
  DropdownField({@required this.onChanged});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButtonFormField(
      onChanged: this.onChanged,
    );
  }
}
```

Then when you instantiate the class, have it manipulate something on callback.

```
class _OtherClassState extends State<OtherClass> {
  var _selectedItem;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownField(
      onChanged: (newItem) => setState(() => this._selectedItem = newItem),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think we should also pass the value in the constructor as the "value" field should also need the selected value.